# local variable referenced before assignment in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, unbound

My program isn't working.

It is meant to be

- you have an array and a code
- if the code is 0 then you have to add up the numbers
- if it is anything else then you have to multiply them
- I want it to use recursion but when you get to less then 5 numbers then I don't use more recursion, I just want do it normally

This is the problem I get

```
    the_rest = sum_or_product(code, array[1:])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum_or_product' referenced before assignment
```

This is the program

```
def sum_or_product(code, array):

    if code == 0:
        do = 'SUM'
    else:
        do = 'PRODUCT'

    # THIS IS WITH THE RECURSION

    if len(array) >= 5:
        this_one = array[0]
        the_rest = sum_or_product(code, array[1:])
        if do == 'SUM':
            return this_one + the_rest
        if do == 'PRODUCT':
            return this_one * the_rest

    # THIS IS WITHOUT THE RECURSION

    if do == 'SUM':
        start = 0

    if do == 'PRODUCT':
        start = 1

    sofar = start

    for i in array:
        if do == 'SUM':
            total = sofar + i
            sofar = total
        if do == 'PRODUCT':
            product = sofar * i
            sofar = product
    sum_or_product = sofar

    return sum_or_product


print(sum_or_product(1, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

It should mutiply all the numbers from 1 to 10. But it just gives an error.

Comment: sum_or_product is a function, not a variable. why do you want to assign a value to a function?

Comment: do you only want to rmultiply code for i in array?

Comment: If the code is 0 I want to add. But if it is not 0 I want to multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return a value from a function, you just

```
return <value>
```

instead of assigning the value to the function.

So in order to fix your code you just need to replace

```
    sum_or_product = sofar

    return sum_or_product
```

with

```
    return sofar
```

As a side note, instead of using obscure conventions like '0 is SUM, 1 is PRODUCT', use constants, e.g.:

```
OP_SUM=0
OP_PRODUCT=1

def sum_or_product(operation, array):

...

    if operation == OP_SUM:
        ...
    elif operation == OP_PRODUCT:
        ...

...

print(sum_or_product(OP_SUM, [2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def sum_or_product(code, array):
    
        return (([code * num for num in array if code != 0 and num <= 5]), ([code + num for num in array if num > 5]))
 print(sum_or_product(2, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

output

```
([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Comment: is this what you need?